# Automated Email Update - Help Needed

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, automated-process

**Background**

I am a BA for a Salesforce programme and having difficult working out the best way to address the following user story below. Salesforce OOB reports and dashboards don't give enough customisation options.

And CRM analytics isn't the clean UI that users are used to from their legacy system.

Could the below be done easy using visualforce / APEX / flow? If so we could get some developer resource to help us in the short term but it would be good to hear the communities thoughts on this - we are just looking for a clean HTML style email.

**Automated email alert - User Story**

As a Sales user, I want to to receive a daily automated email alert similar to the legacy's system daily business update (screenshot attached)

Acceptance Criteria:

The email should display three separate sections: Pipeline (New), Pipeline (Updated), and Pipeline (Closed).

The Pipeline (New) section should include a table that lists all the opportunities created today. The table should include the following data fields: opportunity name, office, type, revenue, wpp status, and industry classification.

The Pipeline (Updated) section should include a table that lists all the opportunities whose status changed today. The table should only include opportunities whose status changed from an existing value to a new one (with conditional formatting to highlight the change). If the status was blank, it should not be included. The table should include the following data fields: opportunity name, office, type, revenue, wpp status, and industry classification.

The Pipeline (Closed) section should include a table that lists all the opportunities closed won/lost today. The table should include the following data fields: opportunity name, office, type, revenue, wpp status, industry classification, and win/loss reason.

The sections should be dynamic, meaning that if the values are equal to zero and no opportunity record was closed today, it should display no information, and the section should be removed entirely.

The email should only trigger if there is data in one of the three sections.

Comment: VF email template with multiple VF components, each with their own custom controller